UnexpectedResponseException when attempting to take screenshot with Selenium Web Driver in PHP
Error:
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\Internal\UnexpectedResponseException: Error taking screenshot, no data received from the remote end

/path/to/app/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/Internal/UnexpectedResponseException.php:14
/path/to/app/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Support/ScreenshotHelper.php:48
/path/to/app/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Support/ScreenshotHelper.php:33
/path/to/app/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:381

Code that is run upon test failure:
protected function setUp(): void
{
    // Start a browser session
    $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::microsoftEdge();

    // Set the options in the capabilities
    $capabilities->setCapability('platformName', 'linux');

    $this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities);
}

...

protected function onNotSuccessfulTest(\Throwable $t): void
{
    $x = $this->driver->takeScreenshot();
    file_put_contents('/path/to/app/test.png', $x);
}

Edit #1 - versions

PHPUnit: 9.6.19
Selenium web-driver: 1.15.1
Selenium Standalone: 4.15.0

Edit #2 - Selenium Grid configuration
2024-05-24 07:59:40 Selenium Grid Standalone configuration: 
2024-05-24 07:59:40 [network]
2024-05-24 07:59:40 relax-checks = true
2024-05-24 07:59:40 
2024-05-24 07:59:40 [node]
2024-05-24 07:59:40 session-timeout = "300"
2024-05-24 07:59:40 override-max-sessions = false
2024-05-24 07:59:40 detect-drivers = false
2024-05-24 07:59:40 drain-after-session-count = 0
2024-05-24 07:59:40 max-sessions = 1
2024-05-24 07:59:40 
2024-05-24 07:59:40 [[node.driver-configuration]]
2024-05-24 07:59:40 display-name = "MicrosoftEdge"
2024-05-24 07:59:40 stereotype = '{"browserName": "MicrosoftEdge", "browserVersion": "119.0", "platformName": "Linux", "ms:edgeOptions": {"binary": "/usr/bin/microsoft-edge"}}'
2024-05-24 07:59:40 max-sessions = 1

